# What does "I put it on myself" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

The following context is from the movie "The Wolf Of Wallstreet" by Martin Scorsese

JORDAN
My job, you know, it's tough. I mean I'm not complaining, it's just the
stress. All these people depending on me. Millions of dollars at                     stake every day. I sometimes feel I've bitten off more than I can chew.

AUNT EMMA
You're a man with large appetites.

*Jordan looks at her and smiles:*

JORDAN
(thinking) Is she fu*%#ng hitting on me?

JORDAN
I agree. **I put it on myself**. It's hard to control the anxiety, you know? It's hard to learn to relax.

One of the synonyms for the word "**put**" is "impose" (to force someone to accept something, especially a belief or way of living{source Camb dic})

Does this mean that he "imposed it on himself"?

Comment: If you're heard it correctly, then yes, that is the meaning. Are you sure he didn't say _I took it on myself_?

Comment: I'm sure. The text is copied from the script anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put something on someone= to cause something to affect someone

Jordan put it on himself. (... caused it to affect...)

I put a lot of stress on myself.

Comment: Hmm, I can't find the definition in a dictionary though. Can anyone provide a link?

Comment: @StaticBounce - It is colloquial and an uncommon usage.  The more common expression is, *I **brought** it on/upon myself* or *I **put** it on someone else.*  *I **put** the blame on Jim and as a result, **brought** ruin upon myself.*

Comment: It's listed as meaning 3 [in Longman's](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/put-on)

Comment: @EllieK I revisited the post on rewatching the movie and I realized that I still exactly don't know what this means. Is "put" in "I put the blame on him" the same as in "I put this burden on myself"? My definition from 2022 below would fit both of these contexts nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I found this definition in the Google dic. I think it fits this context. Can anyone confirm?

**put on**
cause someone or something to be subject to something unwelcome or unpleasant.
*"commentators put some of the blame on Congress"*